# LimInf $\sum \frac{2^{n}}{n!}z^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on my own created example and am having trouble finding the LimInf $\sum \frac{2^{n}}{n!}z^{n}$  I found the limSup  = 0 ( i think) ... so if the series converges, then is the LimInf = 0 too?  i think so....  hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $z \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!}z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2z)^n}{n!}$ converges to $e^{2z}$. Hence, $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ should both be $e^{2z}$.

Comment: From what I calculate using the Ratio test  we have LimSup$|\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{2^{n}}|$ = 2LimSup$|\frac{1}{n+1}|$ $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  this implies the set is convergent with the radius of convergence equal to $\mathbb{R}$.  for calculating the power series, we do not include the power $z^{n}$ and only the coefficient. s o i don't think your response is correct??  ty vm

Comment: I checked wolfram, and it matches your answer, do you mind giving a hint, I think I stand corrected... but my results for limit sup just shows it converges...

Comment: The Taylor series expansion for $e^x$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$. So, by the sum $\sum (2z)^n/n!$ should be $e^{2z}$. And since the limit exists, limsup and liminf should both be equal to the limit.

Comment: how is my use of the ratio test fail then?  how come our conclusions differ?  my ratio test is wrong then?  hmm

Comment: @AnthonyColombo shouldn't you include $z^n$ in your ratio test also?

Comment: I could be mistaken (math novice) but the definition of ratio test uses only the coefficients.  (our TA has confirmed this as well).  but I think our answers do align, because my radius of convergence is actually $+ \infty$ which corresponds to the limit solution $e^{2x}$ which is defined on this interval.  so I think we can close this discussion?  thank you.  agree or no?

Comment: @AnthonyColombo http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioTest.html it's the whole term.

Comment: I see... according to Rudin (has errors) pg 69  it says explicitly "given the power series $\sum c_{n}z^{n}$ put $\alpha = lim sup |c_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ where for root test we use only the coefficients.  i assume that we do the same for ratio test.  so I cam 90% sure for testing the lim sup, we use only the coefficients.  however, when calculating the exact limit via taylor series, yes we need the powers for the polynomial.  not for lim sup though.  i think i am satisfied to close this discussion.  see Rudin pg 69